# Avoiding duplication between main and testing persistence units

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, openjpa

I have two persistence units with the same name, one in `src/main/resources`, another in `src/test/resources`. However, there is some information which is the same between them: list of entity classes, some (not all) properties, etc. How can I avoid duplicating it? If the answer depends on JPA implementation, I am interested in both OpenJPA and EclipseLink.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid having a persistence.xml file in your main and test directories?

Comment: @Rick No, or not necessarily. Just to factor out things they have in common.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass persistence unit properties at runtime in Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Map).

If they are separate persistence units they should have different names...

Comment: It's the same persistence unit in two different configurations: one for normal use, and another for unit testing.

Comment: Maybe just keep one unit instead of two? Also if they are the same unit, how their properties are different? You mentioned not all properties are common.